# Check if a Google account profile picture have been updated

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm writing an Android application that make use of user's profile picture.
I would like to cache these pictures, and re-download them only if they have been updated since I last got them.

a skeleton code to what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public foo() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    try {
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (currentPerson != null) {
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            // ========================================
            // Here I would like to be able to tell if the image pointed by personPhotoUrl have been updated since
            // the last time I've downloaded it, before I need to re-download it.
            // ========================================               
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Identification error, please try again later" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I tested to see, if when changing the profile picture, also the URL is changing, and found out it didn't.

Is there any way to tell if a google+ profile picture have been updated?

Comment: Is standard caching ETag or IfModifiedSince applicable?

Comment: @MarekSevera I don't think ifModifedSince is supported since i don't see Last-Modified among the http headers. ETag might work. I'll try and update.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain the image URL didn't change? I'm 99% sure they will. Perhaps the image url you got was cached on the device and once synced would change.

Comment: I'm quite positive, I tested it on my own account before and after changing the my profile picture. Got the same URL in both cases and it was pointing to the right image each time.